# ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '1'

Tags: python, csv

I am coding a game and a leader board for it. I have the high score and it is stored in a csv file, if someone beats it, the new high score overwrites the old high score however I am getting an error which I don't understand.

Here is my relevant code:

```
with open ("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\High_score.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
        writecsv=csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(str(NumberOfGuesses))
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/sophie/Documents/Sophie/Homework/Year 11/Computer 
Science/Summer homework.py", line 124, in <module>
    writer.writerow(str(NumberOfGuesses))
    File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
    File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 149, in _dict_to_list+ ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
    ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '1'
```

At the start I read the csv file and set the variable high_score to the high score in the file.

```
high_score = ()
    import csv
    with open
("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year11\\ComputerScience\\Highscore.csv") as csvfile:
            readcsv=csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in readcsv:
                high_score=(row)
```

Then the user plays the game and if they have beaten the high score, I want it to overwrite the high score in that folder and replace it with the new one.

This is shown here

```
if NumberOfGuesses <= (int_high_score):#This shows the high score changes value if that score is higher.

    with open ("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\High_score.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
        writecsv=csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(str(NumberOfGuesses))
```

Comment: what does `NumberOfGuesses` look like?

Comment: NumberOfGuesses is a variable which increments by one every time they guess a number and it is wrong. It's like a mastermind sort of game and then if they beat the highest score, it should save to a csv file but I'm getting this weird error.

Comment: The error is from csv.DictWriter, which is used for writing dictionaries to csv.  This error wouldn't be thrown by passing a string to the default csv writer. To reproduce this error, I had to write:
 `with open('test.csv','w') as f:

    w = csv.DictWriter(f,['anything'])

    w.writerow({1:'s'})
`

Comment: perhaps add a bit more code, and examples of the data.

Comment: I'm passing an integer through, is this still the case @user2583933

Comment: `str(NumberOfGuesses)` means you're passing a string through. It would still be the case with an integer though. The crux of this is that for whatever reason, the writer being used is `csv.DictWriter`.  That's why I'm asking for more code, the error doesn't make sense for the code you've posted.

Comment: if my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've spotted what's wrong with the code:

```
with open ("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\High_score.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writecsv=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(str(NumberOfGuesses))
```

On that second line, you instanciate `writecsv` as the writer, but on the third line, you write to *some* csv, using a different writer, called `writer`

Presumably `writer` is from somewhere else in your code. Change the code to:

```
with open ("C:\\Users\\sophie\\Documents\\Sophie\\Homework\\Year 11\\Computer Science\\High_score.csv", 'w') as csvfile:
    writecsv=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writecsv.writerow(str(NumberOfGuesses))
```

And that will solve this particular error.

Comment: Happy to help. Gimme an upvote, accept the answer, gimme the karma :D.

Comment: Also props for doing coding in secondary school, and with python, and during the summer holidays! Python is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

So i've had to code something similar a few days ago, here's how i did it :

```
def writeFile(path,x):
    returnList = []
    returnList.append(x)
    with open(path,'w') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=' ', lineterminator='\n')
        spamwriter.writerow(returnList)
```

In your code I noticed 2 things :

First, you name a csv.writer object, and do not use it again on the second line :

```
writecsv=csv.writer(csvfile)
writer.writerow(str(NumberOfGuesses))
```

I have no idea why, but from experience, writerow seems to only work with lists ; so you may want to add your integer to a list before trying to write it.